# Найти наименьшее из значений элементов столбца, который имеет наибольшую сумму модулей элементов

Tags: java, матрицы

[image: код, который просто находит сумму столбцов и их минимальный элемент]

Как мне сделать так чтобы программа находила наименьшее из значений элементов столбца, который имеет наибольшую сумму модулей элементов. И если таких столбцов несколько, то находило минимальный из них.
Буду очень благодарна за помощь.

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] mas = new int[10][10];

        for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mas[i].length; j++) {
                mas[i][j] = (int) ((Math.random()*300)-15);
                out.print(mas[i][j] + " ");
            }
            out.println();

        }
        int min = mas[0][0];
        int max = mas[0][0];
        int sum = 0;
        out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < mas[0].length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mas.length; j++) {
                if (min > mas[j][i]) {
                    min = mas[j][i];
                }
                if (max < mas[j][i]) {
                    max = mas[j][i];
                }
                sum += mas[j][i];
            }

            out.print("Сумма столбца № " + i + " составляет " + sum + " \n");
            out.print("Минимальный элемент " + min + " \n\n");

            min = sum = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стратегия будет такая: 
1 - сначала найдем все интересующие нас значения: суммы модулей и минимальный элемент для каждого столбца, т.к. сам массив массивов нас не особо интересует
2 - потом пройдемся по ним и найдем из них самые лучшие и нужные согласно условию
Итак, поехали:

```
    // заполняем как бы матрицу случайными числами
    int[][] mas = new int[10][10];
    for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mas[i].length; j++) {
            mas[i][j] = (int) ((Math.random() * 300) - 15);
            System.out.print(mas[i][j] + "\t"); // выводим более читаемым способом
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    // создаем два вспомогательных массива с суммами модулей и минимальными значениями элементов для столбцов
    int[] sum = new int[mas[0].length];
    int[] min = new int[mas[0].length];

    for (int j = 0; j < mas.length; j++) {
        int localMin = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int localSum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mas[0].length; i++) {
            localSum += Math.abs(mas[i][j]);
            if (mas[i][j] < localMin) localMin = mas[i][j];
        }
        sum[j] = localSum;
        min[j] = localMin;
    }

    // проверяем то что нашли
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sum));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(min));

    // ищем во вспомогательных массивах максимальную сумму || если суммы совпадают минимальный элемент
    int maxSum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int columnNumber = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < sum.length; i++) {
        if (sum[i] > maxSum || (sum[i] == maxSum && min[i] < minValue)) {
            maxSum = sum[i];
            minValue = min[i];
            columnNumber = i+1;
        }
    }

    // проверяем результат
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("Столбец %d; Сумма %d; Минимальный элемент %d.", columnNumber, maxSum, minValue);

}
```

Прибавляем единичку к номеру столбца, ведь для компьютера первый элемент массива имеет индекс 0, а для человека 1;

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Просто выполните буквально требования задачи.

При обходе каждого столбца ищется минимум именно в столбце. 
Одновременно считается сумма **модулей** элементов. 
После обхода каждого столбца проверяется, не является ли текущая сумма максимальной среди пройденных. Если да, то текущий минимум запоминается.

Здесь подразумевается, что во фразе "если таких столбцов несколько, то находило минимальный из них." имеется в виду минимальное из минимальных значений.

```
    int maxsum = -1;
    int bestmin;
    for (int i = 0; i < mas[0].length; i++) {
        int min = mas[0][i];
        int max = mas[0][i];
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < mas.length; j++) {
            if (min > mas[j][i]) 
                min = mas[j][i];
            sum += Math.abs(mas[j][i]);
        }
        if (maxsum == sum)
             bestmin = Math.min(min, bestmin);
        if (maxsum < sum) {
                maxsum = sum;
                bestmin = min;
        }
    }
```